# Why update and insert is not working in the query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to insert one-column data from one table to another table based on a same "id" value. I executed following query and it ran successfully and showed all rows are affected in the message. But when I checked the table, it showed blank value for each row of that column. So, no data was inserted.

```
insert into edge_table (code)
    select d.code as code from d_k as d inner join edge_table as edge on d.segm_id = edge.segm_id
```

Then I tried with UPDATE. Executed following query. And it gave an error: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

```
update edge_table set (code) = 
    (select d.code as code from d_k as d inner join edge_table as edge on d.segm_id = edge.segm_id)
```

But when I tried only select, it worked fine.

```
select d.code as code from d_k as d inner join edge_table as edge on d.segm_id = edge.segm_id
```

Comment: The error message says it all, your sub-query returns more than one row. It needs a reference to the update table as well!

Comment: number of  data u r fetching from the select query is more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want this:

```
update edge_table 
    set code = d.code
    from d_k d
    where d.segm_id = edge_table.segm_id ;
```

This updates the existing values in `edge_table` that have matches in `d_k`.

Note:  You have an issue in the data, because there are multiple matches for a given row in `edge_table`.  This will update using an arbitrary matching row.